# PDO and SQL IN statements

Tags: php, sql, mysql, pdo

Im using a sequel for search like this using PDOs

```
$states = "'SC','SD'";  
$sql = "select * from mytable where states in (:states)";  
$params = array(':states'=>$states);
```

and I use my function

```
$result = $this->selectArrayAssoc($sql, $params);
```

where my selectArrayAssoc function as following

```
public function selectArrayAssoc($sql, $params = array())
{
  try {
     $sth = $this->db->prepare($sql);
     $sth->execute($params);
     $result = $sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
     return $sth->fetchAll();
  } catch(PDOException $e) {
     print $e->getMessage();
     //Log this to a file later when in production
     exit;
  }
}
```

it does not take the quoted variables, I think it is suppressing, in such cases how to deal with this.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/php-pdo-can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition

Answer (score 3):

When using prepared statement placeholders (parameter binding) in general, each occurrence of a placeholder holds exactly one variable.

You're trying to pass several. What's happening is basically that your parameters are escaped: Your **:states** is replaced with **'''SC'',''SD'''** or **'\'SC\',\'SD\''** internally, rather than with just the raw **'SC','SD'** that you want.

Comment: so how do I exactly pass my values here, I implode it from an array and get them like this('sc','sd') here. I tried various quoting methods, everything seem to be failing.

Comment: You don't want to quote them. Given `$states = "'SC','SD'";` and `$sql = "select * from mytable where states in (:states)";`, you'll want `$sql = "select * from mytable where states in ('SC','SD')";`. Take a look at the question **Tom Haigh** linked you to.

Comment: got answer from one of other questions, thank you pinkgothic

Comment: That's not really what true prepared statements do, they don't really replace or add quotes, but instead they treat them as *parameters*, which are "injected" into the prepared query on the server (mysql) side.

Comment: Yeah, you're right; I just find it's easier to understand in those terms. :)

Answer (score 2):

pinkgothic is absolute correct. But I think you got the problem, that you have an array of 'states' and want work with this array. You've to prepare the Placeholder for each value in the query.

```
$states = array('SC','SD');
$phArray = array();
$valArray = array();

foreach($ids AS $key=>$value){
  array_push($phArray, ':PH' . $key);
  $valArray[':PH' . $key] = $value;
}

$sql = 'select * from mytable where states in (' . implode(',', $phArray) . ')';
$params = array($valArray);
$result = $this->selectArrayAssoc($sql, $params);
```