# Pass comma separated values through php script into sql query

Tags: php, sql, arguments

I'm passing an argument to my php code using a web brower in the following format:

```
www.site.php?age=1&sex=2
```

Then in the code accessing those arguments:

```
'age' => $_GET['age']
'sex' => $_GET['sex']
```

One argument needs to be a set of comma separated values (ie, "1,2,3,4,5").  When I do the following, only the first value gets interpreted:

```
www.site.php?age=1&sex=2&nums=1,2,3,4,5
```

I've tried with parens, brackets, etc., which all break the code.  Any thoughts?  Thanks,

EDIT: I incorrectly assumed when the error occurred.  The error occurs when trying to actually make the sql call:

This works:

```
$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT * from db
    WHERE age=:age AND nums in (1,2)
SQL;
$query = $dbs['base']['connection']->prepare($sql);

$query->execute(array(
    ':age'      => $_GET['age'],

));
```

But it fails when I pass in the nums:

```
$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT * from db
    WHERE age=:age AND nums in (:nums)
SQL;
$query->execute(array(
        ':age'      => $_GET['age'],
            ':nums'  => $_GET['nums']
    ));
```

When I just print $_GET['nums'], the comma separated values come in just fine.  How can I properly pass the 'nums' argument to the sql query?

Comment: What is the value of `$_GET['nums']`? Just get it from that element and use `explode`?

Comment: I'm using it in a sql query saying WHERE num IN (1,2,3,4,6)

Comment: But what value do you actually get from the $_GET variable?

Comment: The value that I'm trying to get is "1,2,3,4,6", commas included

Comment: then just use `explode` to split it. Passing it straight to the DB is bad practise without escaping it first.

Comment: The problem is that only the first value is coming through when I pass the comma separated values into the web browser.

Comment: Can't be right. Use `print_r($_GET);` or $_SERVER to debug. Probably your database query which is built wrong.

Comment: Yep, figured that out just before reading this -- how can I properly pass into the sql query?

Comment: see [PDO and SQL IN statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681281/pdo-and-sql-in-statements)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `urlencode`?

```
// set
$nums = urlencode(join(',', array(1,2,3,4,5)));

// get
$nums = explode(',', urldecode($_GET['nums']));
// i think needs sanitize
$nums = array_map('intval', $nums);
```

Comment: The screen just prints "array" when I try that:$nums = explode(',', urldecode($_GET['nums']));
print($nums);     What am I missing?

Comment: But when I just do $nums =  urldecode($_GET['causes']), I get "1,2,3,4,5"

Comment: Yes, but you need to filter `$nums` for security. After filter, can use `join()` to get `1,2,3`.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the comma's into something more friendly on the sending page

```
$nums = "1,2,3,4,5";
$nums = str_replace(',','|',$nums);
```

In the page receiving the GET do the following:

```
$nums = str_replace('|',',',$nums);
```

Answer (score 0):

URL encode the commas if you want a string?

```
www.site.php?age=1&sex=2&nums=1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5
```

Also, HTTP has an array format for parameters that PHP could interpret automatically for you. I forget the syntax offhand, but it's pretty straightforward.

Edit 2: Nevermind, you want the string.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear on why a test like this doesn’t work for you. Note the `<pre>` and `print_r()` are strictly there for debugging. `explode(',', $_GET['nums'])` is the key.

```
echo '<pre>';
$nums_array = explode(',', $_GET['nums']);
print_r($nums_array);
echo '</pre>';
```

Maybe you need to share part of the parsing code with us to better understand?

Answer (score 0):

With your current database interface, you can't. It uses prepared statements. Your list will be converted into a string, thus no longer be a value list to the `IN` clause.

This is why I'm for example using something like this:

```
db("SELECT * from t1 WHERE id=? AND x IN (??)", $id, $array);
```

You'll however have to manually create some `?,?,?,?,?` placeholders <sup>1</sup>, depending on the input list length (after the mentioned explode, or better str_getcsv splitting). And yes you need enumerated parameters, not :named ones.

<sup>1</sup> Precisely because it's boring/tedious I'm not providing sample code here.